# Systemd start-up service for gunicorn stays inactive

Tags: systemd, gunicorn

I have configured the gunicorn.py configuration file to start the python server which is binded to the nginx. Everything works fine except the start up service. I am using the systemd Service configuration, here is the gunicorn service:

```
[Unit]
Description = gunicorn daemon
#Requires = gunicorn.socket
After = network.target

[Service]
#PIDFile = /run/gunicorn.pid
WorkingDirectory = /var/www/LTT/ltt
Group = devs
User = root
Type = forking
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -c gunicorn.py app_ltt:app
ExecReload = /bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop = /bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

here is the inactive message when try to start (however the service is enabled) [GUNICORN service status upon systemctl start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Qwy.png).

Someone recommended to add daemon=True to gunciorn config to work, but it doesn't help.

```
#Bidnign
bind = 'unix:/var/www/LTT/ltt/gunicorn.sock'
backlog = 2048
#Workers
#num = 1+2-4 x $NUM_CORES
workers = 1
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
#Fct
spew = False
#Server
umask = 007
daemon = True
user = 'www-data'
group = 'www-data'
pidfile = '/run/gunicorn.pid'
```

**LOG UPDATE**
I added errorlog.log with debug mode to gunicorn config file, when i run the command myself it works and writes to the files, but when i run **systemctl start gunicorn** it doesn't even create the files, so i can't read the logs.

```
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/accesslog.log'
errorlog = '/var/log/gunicorn/errorlog.log'
loglevel = 'debug'
```

**LOG UPDATE-2**
I have chown gunicorn to www-data and used it in the gunicorn service, it starts gunicorn (writes it to the log) but no further actions (listening to socket, starting gevent worker). here is the log output:
[GUNICORN error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlpGb.png)

Comment: Gunicorn shut itself down normally. Check its logs to find out why.

Comment: Hello, i have tried to check the gunicorn logs but they are not created when i run the gunicorn via systemctl start. It doesn't seem to start, even if its exit status is 0. If you have an idea how could i debug it will help me a lot.

Comment: After i chown gunicorn it writes the log, where i can read that it starts gunicorn but never connects to the socket or starts the workers